# .htaccess code to enforce adding www to domain name

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using the following .htaccess configuration to rewrite URL:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteOptions Inherit
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule  (.*)                index.php?query=$1        [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

Options -Indexes
```

My purpose is when users type `abc.com/home.html`, it will automatically translate into `abc.com/index.php?query=home.html`.

However, if I use firefox to access my current website, and if I type www.abc.com in the Address Bar, everything is good, but if I type abc.com (not begin with www), errors occurr. I look up for help on web and there is a guide to add the following .htaccess configuration to force adding www to the front of abc.com, but I do not know how to combine this .htaccess code with my old .htaccess code. Please help:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Only in firefox? Other browsers work without the www?

Comment: I have just checked, it happens in IE also, but not in Chrome. It works fine in Chrome. I am not familier with Apache, and have not learned how to combine the 2 above code yet.